# Refreshing RecyclerView adapter every 1 second

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

Below is my implementation for recycler view.

The recycler view is refreshing but the view is lagging alot making it not smooth to scroll.
If I dont refresh data the recyclerView is smooth.
The problem is with refreshing only..!!

I need to refresh data completely every 1 sec in RecyclerView maintaining same scroll position.

**xml**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyView_disp_pgms"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

**Activity :**

```
RecyclerView recyView_disp_pgms = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyView_disp_pgms);

DisplayProgramsAdapterRecycler pgmAdapter = new DisplayProgramsAdapterRecycler(programsList);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyView_disp_pgms.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyView_disp_pgms.setAdapter(pgmAdapter);


handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("AllPgm Runflag : " + runflag);
            programList = // Get List from database

           if (programsList != null && programsList.size() > 0) {
            if (pgmAdapter != null && pgmAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                pgmAdapter.resetData(programsList);
            }
        }


            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    handler.post(runnable);
```

**Adapter :**

```
 public void resetData(ArrayList<ProgramDetails_Table> programsList) {
    this.programDetailsList = programsList;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Problem - Lagging scroll of recyclerView only while refreshing data for every 1 sec**

Tried following other posts; but still no luck.
Please help..!!

Comment: You said ' The recycler view is refreshing '. So what do you want here?

Comment: I want the recyclerview scrolling to be smooth ; as of now its refresing list every 1 sec and recyclerview is quite laggy ...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to refresh your list find your changes and then just notify that position because notifyDataSetChanged resets all of your data.
you should use lightweight notifies.something like this:

```
    notifyItemChanged(yourPosition);
    notifyItemInserted(yourPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(yourPosition);
```

or if you get more than one change in a range you can use:

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(yourPosition);//and etc
```

Comment: I want to refresh whole list ; as I wont come to know whats items in list are changed and how many are changed.. I used notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list.size()); this make recyclerview more slow

Comment: @RiteshKarmare notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list.size()); is same as notifyDataSetChanged, i suggest you to calculate your programList changes(if changes count is fewer than your list size) and then just notify these changes, because notifyDataSetChange on a big arrayList is slow and you cant make it faster.

Comment: In my recyclerView Items there are 4 textView ; if for two items one of the textview is change how do i update the adapter.... how can i track which item is changed

Comment: @RiteshKarmare, the update to RecycleView adapter happens via Async Calls. That's why there are so many callbacks. When you do insert/delete and do notifyDataSetChange(), there Adapter knows you want update and it updates.

Comment: i want to keep on refreshing the entire adapter every 1 sec , whick is updating.. the problem is laggy scroll view of recyclerView

Answer (score 1):

use `DiffUtil`. Don't use `notifyDataSetChanged`.

According to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html,

> DiffUtil is a utility class that can calculate the difference between
>   two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the
>   first list into the second one.
>
> It can be used to calculate updates for a RecyclerView Adapter.

Unlike the `notifyDataSetChanged` method, it does not reload the whole list so it has a better performance.

And you don't have to manually find the differences between the new and the old list like the other `notifyData` methods from `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Comment: You will need to explain what `DiffUtil` is, and does, otherwise this answer could be scrubbed as being too low-quality

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling notifyDataSetChanged() inside the resetData function.

Also, try this instead of assigning directly to programList

```
programList.clear();
programList.addAll(arrayListOfDataFromServer);
```

Comment: instead of assigning the new ArrayList to the programList try to clear it and add each value from the new list to the programList using addAll, check edited answer

Comment: I had tried the above solution also ; but the problem here seem to be laggy scrolling because of 1 sec refreshing

Answer (score 0):

Delete your line `this.programDetailsList = programsList;` and add the following. This is a simple hack, a way that makes you understand Async Callbacks.

```
/* I have done adding one element and then deleting the same element as the last element of programsList */
/* adding and deleting triggers notifyDataChange() callback */

//add an element in index 0 as the last element into the programList
programsList.add(programsList.size() - 1, programsList.get(0));

//remove the same last element from ProgramList
programsList.add(programsList.size() - 1);

//now it works
this.notifyDataSetChanged(programsList.size() - 1);
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is working in existing code.... the problem is with laggy scrolling of recyclerView

Comment: @RiteshKarmare, notifyDataSetChanged() is a callback which is controlled by AsyncTask at the backend. notifyDataSetChanged(index) only tracks data set change in the particular index so it is more efficient. The logic behind I put programList.size() -1 as an index is ==> recycler view keep update of listitems, the last one updated item is at programList.size() -1. If your programList.size() is too big, your screen can only hold 5 items (for instance) then, when you do notifyDataSetChanged(0), system must create new ListItem to hold new item in your recyclerview.

Comment: The laggy, you are making, because you are not recycling list items; instead you should use programsList.size() - 1 as an index.